# Searching a formatted address in SQL table where columns are split

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I go about searching (and possibly full-text index searching) on a table for address data that is structured as per below:

```
address table
+----+------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+-------+----------+
| id | unit | number | street |  type  |    town     | state | postcode |
+----+------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+-------+----------+
|  0 |    2 |     12 | Smith  | Street | Springfield | NSW   |     1234 |
|  1 |    0 |     16 | Bob    | Road   | Faketown    | VIC   |     4321 |
+----+------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+-------+----------+
```

When searching for an address I'd like to search for the whole address. Ideally I'd like to be able to search the table like this:

```
SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE address LIKE "%12 Smith Street%"
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Consider storing the full address in a single column and then using full text search.

Comment: thanks, I had considered that - but it's quite a large database and if I can reduce the amount of duplicate data stored in the table then that would be ideal.

Comment: Try it Tim's way. See what that does to performance vs memory, then look up the cost of more memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend `concat_ws()` in this case over `concat()`:

```
where concat_ws(' ', number, street, type, unit) like '%12 Smith Street%'
```

Not only is it shorter to type and less prone to error, but it ignores `NULL` values.  If any value for `concat()` is `NULL` the entire result is `NULL`.

However, for multi-column full-text search, you should consider using [`match()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html).  Full text search gives you more flexibility on the searching, although you need to be careful about stop words and short words.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to create a string from the columns.

```sql
select CONCAT(number, ' ', street, ' ', type) address
  from address_table
 where address like '%12 Smith Street%'
```

You didn't say what the data types are of the columns in `address_table`. You may need to convert numerical columns to strings.